Problems with Python's azure.cognitiveservices.speech when installing together with FFmpeg in a Linux web app
I need some help.
I'm building an web app that takes any audio format, converts into a .wav file and then passes it to 'azure.cognitiveservices.speech' for transcription.I'm building the web app via a container Dockerfile as I need to install ffmpeg to be able to convert non ".wav" audio files to ".wav" (as azure speech services only process wav files). For some odd reason, the 'speechsdk' class of 'azure.cognitiveservices.speech' fails to work when I install ffmpeg in the web app. The class works perfectly fine when I install it without ffpmeg or when i build and run the container in my machine.
I have placed debug print statements in the code. I can see the class initiating, for some reason it does not buffer in the same when when running it locally in my machine. The routine simply stops without any reason.
Has anybody experienced a similar issue with azure.cognitiveservices.speech conflicting with ffmpeg?
Here's my Dockerfile:
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent imageFROM python:3.11-slim

#Version RunRUN echo "Version Run 1..."

Install ffmpeg

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg && # Ensure ffmpeg is executablechmod a+rx /usr/bin/ffmpeg && # Clean up the apt cache by removing /var/lib/apt/lists saves spaceapt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

//Set the working directory in the container

WORKDIR /app

//Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app

COPY . /app

//Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

//Make port 80 available to the world outside this container

EXPOSE 8000

//Define environment variable

ENV NAME World

//Run main.py when the container launches

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "main.py", "--server.port", "8000", "--server.address", "0.0.0.0"]`and here's my python code:

def transcribe_audio_continuous_old(temp_dir, audio_file, language):
    speech_key = azure_speech_key
    service_region = azure_speech_region

    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"DEBUG TIME BEFORE speechconfig")

    ran = generate_random_string(length=5)
    temp_file = f"transcript_key_{ran}.txt"
    output_text_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, temp_file)
    speech_recognition_language = set_language_to_speech_code(language)
    
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language = speech_recognition_language
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=os.path.join(temp_dir, audio_file))
        
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_input, language=speech_recognition_language)
    done = False
    transcript_contents = ""

    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"DEBUG TIME AFTER speechconfig")
    print(f"DEBUG FIle about to be passed {audio_file}")

    try:
        with open(output_text_file, "w", encoding=encoding) as file:
            def recognized_callback(evt):
                print("Start continuous recognition callback.")
                print(f"Recognized: {evt.result.text}")
                file.write(evt.result.text + "\n")
                nonlocal transcript_contents
                transcript_contents += evt.result.text + "\n"

            def stop_cb(evt):
                print("Stopping continuous recognition callback.")
                print(f"Event type: {evt}")
                speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
                nonlocal done
                done = True
            
            def canceled_cb(evt):
                print(f"Recognition canceled: {evt.reason}")
                if evt.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                    print(f"Cancellation error: {evt.error_details}")
                nonlocal done
                done = True

            speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_callback)
            speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
            speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(canceled_cb)

            speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
            while not done:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("DEBUG LOOPING TRANSCRIPT")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    print("DEBUG DONE TRANSCRIPT")

    return temp_file, transcript_contents

The transcript this callback works fine locally, or when installed without ffmpeg in the linux web app. Not sure why it conflicts with ffmpeg when installed via container dockerfile. The code section that fails can me found on note #NOTE DEBUG"

The provided Dockerfile and Python code do not directly show any clear indication of a conflict between these components.

Below is a basic outline of how you could build a web app that achieves the described functionality using Docker, Flask, ffmpeg, and Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK.

Dockerfile:
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Install any needed dependencies specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

requirements.txt:
Flask==2.0.2
azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.23.0

app.py:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

# Path to store uploaded audio files
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

# Function to convert audio to WAV using ffmpeg
def convert_to_wav(input_file, output_file):
    subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-ac', '1', '-ar', '16000', output_file])

# Route to handle file upload
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file part'})

    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'error': 'No selected file'})

    if file:
        filename = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename)
        file.save(filename)
        wav_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.wav'
        convert_to_wav(filename, wav_filename)
        # Code to call Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK for transcription
        # Replace the below code with your actual Azure Speech SDK code
        transcript = "This is a dummy transcript."
        return jsonify({'transcript': transcript})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)

azure_transcription.py:

Separate script to handle transcription using Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK. This script can be invoked from app.py after converting the audio to WAV

import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

def transcribe_audio_wav(audio_file):
    speech_key = "YourSpeechServiceKey"
    service_region = "YourServiceRegion"
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=audio_file)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_input)
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        return result.text
    else:
        return "Unable to recognize speech"



Thank you. But I'm still struggling. I want to run the solution using streamlit, as I want to build the solution within the same app. Also, my audio files are rather long, 2 to 3 hours long (even more). The function speech_recognizer.recognize_once() works for relatively short audio files, not for long ones - which explains why I use the callback routine instead. The callback is the routine that fails. The web app initiates correctly, but stops shortly after for some odd reason.
I can't really tell what is wrong. Everything works well when I build and test the app locally, and everything works well when I don't install ffmpeg in the same app as azure.cognitiveservices.speech. It puzzles me. The solution so far is to run two separate applications (one for conversion, and one for transcription), but I find that solution rather costly.
I'll keep investigating.
